# WKWebView how to load HTTPS?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I use WKWebView to load HTTPS , but it does not work.
The function

```
webView(
   webView: WKWebView, 
   didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge,
   completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void)
```

can do it maybe, please tell me how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your server's certificate is signed by a trustful CA, you can get the default behavior from NSURLSession, which means you can behave as Safari.
If you want to use your authentication method, you can use the delegate method you mentioned to customize your authentication.